# got has triggered a breakpoint error when load url

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I use cefsharp(version:92.260) in my application. the application may crash when loading url, but not always.

below is my code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var spinWait = new SpinWait();
    while(!_Browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        spinWait.SpinOnce();
    }
    _Browser.Load(url);
});
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the crash. Could you post a text, not the image and the crash message.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you upgrade to a supported version, 103 at time of writing.

Improvements have been made, no longer is it nessicary to wait for IsBrowserInitialized to be equal to true before you can call Load(url).

You can just call Load without the IsBrowserInitialized check.